# Cannot see directories and files in the Bluemix Web IDE

Tags: ibm-cloud

I created an application on my desktop, added an `index.html` in the `public` directory and a JavaScript file in the `lib` directory. I pushed the application to Bluemix where I wanted to adapt the JavaScript file (watson-developer-cloud) in the Web IDE. However, in the Web IDE, I don't see all the files and folders, only:

```
.git
launchConfigurations
.cfignore
License.txt
README.md
```

How can I get in the right directory?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Is it "Where did my custom Bluemix app publish the file to?" or is it "How do I search for files in the WEB IDE?"

Comment: Do you have a link to your Web IDE? (Are you using Bluemix DevOps services?) Is this a GitHub repo? How particularly are you pushing your local application to Bluemix? We need some more information to help you out.

Answer (score -1):

Please see this link:

https://hub.jazz.net/code/edit/edit.html#/code/file/jps-JazzSandbox/jps%2520%257C%2520myacp/

I used `cf push` on my Mac.

I can see this link to https://hub.jazz.net/git/jps/myacp, which seems to be IBM DevOps.

Comment: I can't access your JazzHub link (permission issues), but I think the problem is that you aren't committing your code change using git.

Comment: I unchecked Private, could you try again? Also, I'm not sure how to commit after the cf push. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: It still won't let me access the first link. If you have the git repository cloned where you did the `cf push`, you can do a `git status` and see if you have modified files.

Comment: Thanks, I watched a git video today and have my local files in the remote repo as well :-)